# Host part of DHCPv6-assigned router address

Tags: dhcp, openbsd, ipv6

I got my IPv6 prefix via dhcpv6 (/48) on my personal (OpenBSD) router. So the inside interface get partially configured by dhcpv6. I would like to know if it's possible to define the host part of it.

Here is my `dhcp6c.conf`:

```
interface re0 {
send ia-pd 0;
send ia-na 0;
send rapid-commit;
};

id-assoc na 0 {
};

## https://www.azabani.com/2015/08/06/modern-openbsd-home-router.html
id-assoc pd 0 {
    prefix-interface re2 {

    ## I want prefix:: as address.
    sla-id 0;

    ## prefix provided by isp is /48, I want my lan to be /64, so I  reduce by 16.
    sla-len 16;
    };
};
```

And here is the re2 (lan interface) addresses :

```
    stephane@mirror:/home/stephane ifconfig re2 inet6
    re2: flags=8b43<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,ALLMULTI,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    lladdr 00:0d:b9:3e:a8:12
    index 3 priority 0 llprio 3
    media: Ethernet autoselect (100baseTX full-duplex,rxpause,txpause)
    status: active
    inet6 fe80::20d:b9ff:fe3e:a812%re2 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x3
    inet6 fd00:2016:22:dec:: prefixlen 64
    inet6 2a06:4000:1576:: prefixlen 64
    inet6 2a06:4000:1576:0:20d:b9ff:fe3e:a812 prefixlen 64
```

The ula address is defined as static address in conf'. The 2a06:4000:1576:: address is also defined statically but ***I would like it to be really automatic***.

The 2a06:4000:1576:0:20d:b9ff:fe3e:a812 comes out of dhcpv6 conf' and I see the network part is automatic (/48 prefix + 0 as assigned in `dhcp6c.conf`). The host part is definitely slaac. This host part I would like to replace to ::

Do you know the way to do it (out of statically define it)?

Answer (score 1):

Just found out the solution :

I need to use the ifid option.

https://www.mankier.com/5/dhcp6c.conf#Prefix_interface_statement

Here is the code I would like to use :

```
id-assoc pd 0 {
    prefix-interface re2 {
    sla-id 0;

    ## prefix provided by isp is /48, I want my lan to be /64, so I reduce by 16.
    sla-len 16;

    ifid 0;
    };
 };
```

But the version of dhcp6c provided to my OS (OpenBSD) does not include this option (yet ?).